# Why the game has a low FPS in device? Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a 3D game with unity, it works fine and smooth when testing it on playmode (720p), but when testing it with 1080p or 1440p or when playing it on real device (Android), it runs with a very low FPS (not smooth) so that impact the game controls and cause a bad user experience.

I already optimized the game, and when running the profiler it show that the game is playing with a good FPS (about 250FPS).

[image: Profiler]

Did you faced that before? and how did you fixed it?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show a video recording of a test.

Comment: Not sure what the question is here, if your game requires too much to be rendered for the "device" to keep up at 1080p or 1440p, doesn't that simply suggest that you have asked too much of it? The question doesn't have any details other than those numbers, not sure what you want people here to contribute with. Optimize the graphics rendering perhaps?

Comment: Don't profile on your computer, profile on the target device to see where the issues are

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I tried deleting all objects (to reduce performance) and let just the principal one, but it still have a low FPS

Comment: 250FPS on a PC doesn't tell much ... most stuff for me runs with `> 900` FpS and still only 60/30 on target devices ;)

Comment: @derHugo So what do advice me to do to increase the FPS? should I use the minimum of objects? or just decrease their sizes?

Comment: Hard to tell .. reduce vertices/faces as much as possible, reduce transparency and other expensive shaders, reduce physics, reduce expensive API calls like `Find` `GetComponent` etc...

Comment: @derHugo In fact, in my scene I instantiate a big number of objects (very small size objects), between 100 and 300 objects. do you think that's the cause of the low FPS? if so, how should I do to instantiate those objects without worrying about FPS?

Comment: @Taik It depends how you're using those objects. Depending on how they're used you may want to look into [object pooling](https://www.raywenderlich.com/847-object-pooling-in-unity), that way you can instantiate a much fewer number of objects and just reuse them to get a performance boost.